# Deploy a lumen project in AWS ec2 with multiple Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, lumen

I need to deploy three site in AWS ec2 ubuntu server (same ip),

- `html`(default site)
- `aaa.com`(www.aaa.com)
- `bbb.com`(www.bbb.com)

**/var/www:**

```
html
  public
    index.html

aaa.com
  public_html
    index.html

bbb.com
  public_html
     app
     bootstrap
     public
     ..
```

`html` and `aaa.com` are pure html project, and `bbb.com` is a lumen project, when I add a .htaccess file , the site will always get the 500 Internal Server Error.
if I remove the `.htaccess` the site will get the 403 Forbidden (because of `Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews`, I guess), how to correctly rewrite the lumen site for `bbb.com` ? any idea?

**`bbb.com`.htaccess file :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/bbb.com.conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin bbb@gmail.com
    ServerName bbb.com
    ServerAlias www.bbb.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.bbb.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/www.bbb.com/public_html>
          Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```